# Python merge sort for a list containing distinct values

Tags: python, mergesort

This code below is what I think should be the implementation of merge sort in Python and it works as expected. It sorts the given list, where we can safely assume that all values are distinct. But after considering some online implementations I am doubtful about mine. So the base question is "Is this even Merge sort?".

```
def merge(arr):
    # base case
    length = len(arr)
    half = length//2
    if length == 1 or length == 0:
        return arr
    # recursive case
    firstHalf = merge(arr[:half])  # sort first half
    secondHalf = merge(arr[half:])  # sort second half
    length_firstHalf = len(firstHalf)
    length_secondHalf = len(secondHalf)
    sortedList = []

    i, j = 0, 0  # variables for iteration
    while i != length_firstHalf and j != length_secondHalf:  # add elements into the new array until either of then two sub arrays is completely traversed
        if firstHalf[i] > secondHalf[j]:
            sortedList.append(secondHalf[j])
            j += 1
            continue
        if firstHalf[i] < secondHalf[j]:
            sortedList.append(firstHalf[i])
            i += 1
    return(sortedList + firstHalf[i:] + secondHalf[j:])  # return the array after adding whats left of sub array which wasnt completely traversed
```

Comment: @200_success thank you for the advice, the code is edited now

Comment: @200_success now its okay i believe

Comment: @200_success thank you for editing. much better now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your immediate concern, yes it is a merge sort.

- The naming is quite unusual. The procedure you call `merge` does the merge sort, and should be called so. The *merge* phase of the merge sort is done by the

  ```
      while i != length_firstHalf and j != length_secondHalf:
  ```

  loop and the subsequent `return`. It is advisable to factor it out into a standalone `merge` procedure. OTOH I don't endorse a complicated return expressions.
- It is unclear why do you limit yourself to the distinct values. The second `if` clause may be safely made into an `else`, and there is no more worries. Notice that your first comparison `firstHalf[i] > secondHalf[j]` *is* the way to handle duplicates.
- Computing `half` doesn't belong to the base case.
- As a nitpick, `length == 1 or length == 0` is a long way to say `length < 2`.

Comment: Using distinct values was the requirement in the question that i was asked to solve. I think if I add this `if firstHalf[i] >= secondHalf[j]` then it can handle duplicate values.